# HOW TO FIX Error in .Hub("AnnotationHub", hub, cache, proxy, localHub, ...)

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am using `REMP` package in R to find methylation in repetitive elements. I have stumbled upon the function `initREMP`, which is giving me the error:

```
remparcel <- initREMP(arrayType = "EPIC", REtype = "Alu",  ncore = 1)
Start Alu annotation data initialization ...  (0 sec.)
Illumina platform: EPIC
Error in .Hub("AnnotationHub", hub, cache, proxy, localHub, ...) : 
  Local database does not exist.
  Repeat call with 'localHub=FALSE'
```

I installed annotationhub package from the bioconductor and tried the function again. Still the error remains.

Comment: Did you repeat the call and add the `localHub = FALSE` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer.If you are working behind a proxy server getAnnotationHub function will not be able to make connection with the URL.Therefor we have to set the proxy using

`library(AnnotationHub)    setAnnotationHubOption("PROXY","https://username:password@proxy:port")`
then try the

`AnnotationHub( hub=getAnnotationHubOption("URL"),
          cache=getAnnotationHubOption("CACHE"),
          proxy=getAnnotationHubOption("PROXY"),
localHub=FALSE)`